# TypeError: 'BasePermissionMetaclass' object is not iterable in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

i looked at other questions regarding this issue and their problems were in the REST_FRAMEWORK = ... values in settings.py file . is there any error in mine ?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 
    'api_basic',# this is my app that uses authtokens
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',

]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
}
```

view:

```
@api_view(['GET', ])
@permission_classes(IsAuthenticated)
def api_hero(request, name):
    try:
        character = Hero.objects.get(name=name)
    except:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    serializer = serializers.HeroSerializer(character)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Show your view.

Comment: @Anonymous done.

Answer (score 4):

so i found the answer my self . the problem was in view

```
@permission_classes(IsAuthenticated) 
here permission classes arguments should be a tuple.
so:

@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
```

is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the permissions in the list for iterable.

**permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]**

Answer (score -1):

`'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',)`
Add the following line to your `settings.py`.

It turns out omitting the last comma from the tuple will throw an error because `'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES'` expects a tuple